# Pass an object created in one class to another class

Tags: java

I have a class named `StatisticFrame`. This class creates an object named `stats` inside a method. How can I pass this object created from `StatisticFrame` class to another class?

Comment: your question does not contain Class name of the Receiving object and stats object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a variable that will point to the receiver object (say of type TargetFrame class) in your StatisticFrame class and then invoke the method (say SetStatsObject(object obj)) defined in the receiver object to receive the object.

your StaticFrame class will look like this

```
class StatisticFrame {

     private TargetFrame targetObject = null;

     public StatisticFrame (TargetFrame obj) {
          this.targetObject = obj;
     }      

     public void Send (Object stats) {
          object stats = GetStatsObject(); // this will create and returns stats object
          targetObject.SetStatsObject(stats);
     }

     //... 
 }
```

and your TargetFrame (the receiving object's class) should look like this

```
class TargetFrame {

     public void SetStatsObject(Object stats) {
            // Do what ever you want with stats
     }

     // .....rest of the methods follows
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the created object as **argument to** another class **constructor or it's method**.

```
class Apples{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplesTestDrive obj = new ApplesTestDrive();
        ApplesSampleTestDrive objOne = new ApplesSampleTestDrive();
        // Pass created object obj as argument to ApplesSampleTestDrive method.
        objOne.paint(obj);

        }
    }

class ApplesTestDrive{
    public String bucket;
    public ApplesTestDrive(){
      bucket = "blue";
    }
}

class ApplesSampleTestDrive{

    public void paint(ApplesTestDrive obj){
        System.out.println("Paint apple one: " + obj.bucket);
    }

}
```

Comment: can't get any easier

Answer (score 1):

`Another class` needs a method as an `argument` that expects your `stats` object and call that method from your class and pass your stats object

```
private void yourmethod(){

 Stats stas =
 AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();
ac.thatMethod(stats);
}


 class AnotherClass {

  public void thatMethod(Stats stats){

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of ways is that you can create method in your "another class" that will accept as argument object you want to pass, and you call that method from your base class

```
class Sender{
    public void createAndSend(Reciever reciver){
        String s="some data from Producer";
        reciver.recieve(s);
    }
}

class Reciever{
    public void recieve(String data){
        System.out.println("I recieved "+data);
    }
}

//lets test it
class TestX{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sender s=new Sender();
        Reciever r=new Reciever();
        s.createAndSend(r);

    }
}
```

output: `I recieved some data from Producer`

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways you can achieve this . either make the return type of method as `stats`  and then in other class you can make object of `StatisticFrame` and call that method.

```
StatisticFrame sf=new StatisticFrame();
Stats st=sf.method();
```

Other way if you don't want to make return type as `Stats` then Make global `private` variable of type `Stats` and assign this in your method, and then one `public` `getter` method will return this object to other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object for the other class that you want to pass the object with the constructor that accepts your newly created object.
 Another way you can use some callback functions using interface

Answer (score 0):

One way :-

Suppose you have one class Xyz
The object that you want make the getter  method for it and in another class Abc make the object of Xyz and with that object call the getter method and store the return of it in your current class

2nd way :-

use inheritance make the class as super

class Abc extends Xyz
By this u will directly gets access to all the objects, methods present in super class

Hope that this make sense to you