# Share objects in classes Java(FX)

Tags: java, javafx

Alright, so hello everyone hope you're having a nice day.

So I'm pretty new to `Java`, however I know most of the basics, so not a *superb* noob at least; and I'm developing a `JavaFX` sample application, just for testing.
So I ran into a problem, I have a Main `class` in which I've created the interface, pretty simple, just a `scene` with 1 `button`.

**Code for Main:**

```
public class Main extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hi I'm a title");

    //Initialize the Button Object
    Button button = new Button();
    button.setText("Bite me");

    //Call the Handlers Class, with the name handlers
    Handlers handlers = new Handlers();
    /*
    Here would go the code to pass the 'button' object to Handlers class
    So then I can do whatever I need in there
     */

    //The Button event, managed by the 'handle' method in Handlers class, that's why the 'handlers' in the
    //parentheses
    button.setOnAction(handlers);

    //Just the scenery, not relevant
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    pane.getChildren().add(button);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300,250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

}

**Code for Handlers:**

```
public class Handlers implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {


//Very sad try of a constructor, so as to pass the 'button' object from Main class
//In here, however I have no idea as to how to pass an Object type and how to receive it
public void Handlers(){

}

//The handle method to manage the 'button.setOnAction' event
//This is where I need the 'button' object to compare the source of the event
//to that specific button, so as to prevent that every single button does the same thing
//'button' object from Main class should go ".equals(button)"
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    Main main = new Main();

    if (event.getSource().equals()){

    }
}
```

}

I'm adding an event to that button, so I've created a Handlers `class` to handle **(dah)** all the events on the Main `class`, the problem rises it's ugly head when I try to pass the 'button' object from `Main` to `Handlers` so then I can get it's source, so that every button doesn't do the same thing.

My question is: **How can I pass the 'button' `object` from `Main` to `Handlers`?** I know that I can use the `Constructor`, the only problem with that is that I still quite don't grasp the functionality of the `Constructor`, nor the correct use of the arguments.

I've read these forums for about 1 hour looking for the solution, and I'm pretty sure I've already encountered it, but due to my ignorance, can't understand it.
The clearest example of this would be:

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360118/pass-an-object-created-in-one-class-to-another-class)

Sorry for the utterly long post, but... I need help :(

Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here that I recommend you learn a little more about before trying to fully tackle your application idea. But I can answer your question and give you some links to get your started.

**Intro**

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399836/can-there-exist-two-main-methods-in-a-java-program) is a post about `main()`, typically you only have one for an application.

**Part I**

Look into class inheritance. In a JavaFX application, your main class will typically `extend Application` and your `main()` method typically calls `Application.launch()`, made available to your main class because of [access control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). Under the hood, `launch()` is calling `Application.start()`. Because you're inheriting all of the things from `Application`, you are required to implement (what is probably, but don't quote me on this) the `abstract` method `start()` to do all your UI work, see [overriding methods](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/method-overriding-in-java-with-example/) and the related [overloading](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java). So, in `start()`, which is pretty much called in every JavaFX application, you then create a button `Handler` that can be assigned to multiple `Button`s on your `Stage`.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hi I'm a title");

        EventHandler eventHandler = new BiteHandler("You've been bitten");

        Button biteMeButton = new Button();
        biteMeButton.setText("Bite me");

        Button biteMeAgainButton = new Button();
        biteMeAgainButton.setText("Bite me again");

        biteMeButton.setOnAction(eventHandler)
        biteMeAgainButton.setOnAction(eventHandler);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(biteMeButton);
        pane.getChildren().add(biteMeAgainButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300,250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**Part II**

Here is the `BiteHandler` class. With this construct, check out [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). You could have a `BiteHandler`, `ChewHandler`, and `LickHandler` that can all be stored in a `List<EventHandler>` due to polymorphism.

With the way `EventHandler` is setup, essentially the `handle()` method is what is called when the `EventHandler` is invoked, a la a button's on click action. So we need to give this thing something to do when the handler is invoked. Since I have no idea how to animate a mouth, I'm just gonna have this thing print to the passed message to the console. Here, I've left a comment about what a constructor is.

```
public class BiteHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private String message_;

    /**
     * Think of a constructor as any other method, however, it is special
     * in that it is named after the class. Because it is named
     * after the class, the compiler knows that the first thing
     * that needs to be done when instantiating this class. A 
     * constructor is "automatic work" that "constructs" your object. 
     * In this class, when you instantiate it, a message is required.
     * this message is stored in a "private class member" to be accessed
     * later on when the bite() method is called
     */
    public BiteHandler(String message) {
        message_ = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        bite();
    }

    public void bite() {
        System.out.println(message_);
    }
}
```

**Finale**

On your application, you will have 2 buttons. When you click either button, the phrase "You've been bitten" will print to the console. This is because each button has the same `BiteHandler`. Pretty fk'ing lack luster for all that work but you've got plenty of homework to do to fully digest this answer

Comment: Thank you so much man, **real** helpful not just with my problem, but made me learn what really matters of Java!
Again thanks good man, have a nice day :D

Comment: @RolinAzmitia No problem, you should throw that answer and upvote my way tho :)